# Delete S3 bucket object using Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

Using S3DeleteObjectsOperator in Airflow does not delete the object in the specified S3 bucket, even though the task shows that it successfully delete

```
delete_s3bucket_files = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_files',
  start_date=start_date,
  bucket='*********************',
  keys='*********************',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)
```

So the task run shows key was deleted but it still exists in my S3 bucket.

```
[2019-09-16 11:39:25,775] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1346: Subtask delete_s3bucket_files [2019-09-16 11:39:25,775] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: daily_database_transfer.delete_s3bucket_files 2019-09-16T09:39:16.873030+00:00 [running]> on host Saurav-macbook.local
[2019-09-16 11:39:25,971] {s3_delete_objects_operator.py:83} INFO - Deleted: ['*********************']
```

Is there something that I am missing here, or is there a way to find out why its not deleting the object?

Comment: Few quick check here **[1]** are you sure the `boto3` client is picking up correct `region_name`; unless explicitly specified / overridden, it often defaults to `us-east-1`? **[2]** Are you sure that the EC2 machine from where this task is being triggered has `delete_object` privilege for the said bucket and prefix (path)?

Comment: There should be no issue with the region name as the other functions like unload and copy and working perfect. 
I am not sure I understand the `delete_object` privilege. Could you please explain how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `S3DeleteBucketOperator` with `force_delete=True` that forcibly delete all objects in the bucket before deleting the bucket.

So you can just do:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_bucket import S3DeleteBucketOperator

delete_s3bucket = S3DeleteBucketOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_task',
  force_delete=True,
  start_date=start_date,
  bucket_name='*********************',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)
```

If you prefer to seperate deletion of files and deletion of bucket you can do:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_bucket import S3DeleteBucketOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3_delete_objects import S3DeleteObjectsOperator

delete_s3bucket_files = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_files',
  start_date=start_date,
  bucket='*********************',
  keys='*********************',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)

delete_s3bucket = S3DeleteBucketOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_task',
  force_delete=False, #bucket will be deleted only if it's empty.
  start_date=start_date,
  bucket_name='*********************',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)

delete_s3bucket_files >> delete_s3bucket
```